# Dynamic Config Loading using cm:managed-properites in Karaf 3.0.5

Tags: osgi, karaf, blueprint-osgi

I have a simple Camel Application bundle which is to be deployed in Karaf 3.0.5 under Apache Service Mix 6.1. The configuration file is placed in etc/ directory (let's say it is named as wf.cfg). I want to have the dynamic config change functionality in my application bundle. So that whenever something is changed in wf.cfg it is immediately available to bundle. For this I have added the following in my blueprint.xml

```
<bean id="configBean"   class="com.jabong.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.config.ConfigBean">
        <cm:managed-properties persistent-id="wf" update-method="refresh" update-strategy="component-managed"/>
    </bean>

public class ConfigBean {
     private String env;
     public String getEnv() {
         return env;
     }
     public void setEnv(String env) {
        this.env = env;
     }
     public void refresh() {
         System.out.println("Config refreshed");
     }
}
```

But whenever I update the wf.cfg file, the refresh method in ConfigBean class is never called.

I, even tried, using managed-service factory.

```
<cm:managed-service-factory id="managed-service-factory"                                factory-pid="wf"                            interface="com.jabong.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.config.ConfigBean"> 
<cm:managed-component class="com.jabong.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.config.ConfigBean">
            <cm:managed-properties persistent-id="" update-strategy="component-managed" update-method="refresh" />
</cm:managed-component>
    </cm:managed-service-factory>
```

But it din't help. Can someone please help me solve this problem.

Please Note: I don't want to use cm:property-placeholder as it reloads the complete context when we change the cfg file. I want to use cm:managed-properties only.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

Refresh method should have an argument `Map<String, String> properties`.

```
public class ConfigBean {
     private String env;
     public String getEnv() {
         return env;
     }
     public void setEnv(String env) {
        this.env = env;
     }
     public void refresh(Map<String, String> properties) {
         System.out.println("Config refreshed");
     }
}
```